Does the reference counter get decremented before or after the custom deleter?
If I create a single shared_ptr with a custom deleter and that shared_ptr gets destroyed the custom deleter will get called - inside that deleter's body what will be the value of the shared_ptr's reference count? 1 or 0?
I couldn't find it in the documentation. Is that something guaranteed by the standard?

The initial use_count is 1. Decrementing has to be atomic. The only reasonable implementation decrements the count, sees that the count is zero, then calls the deleter

But I also don't see the point to this. The deleter is called once the last shared_ptr is destroyed. The only way to observe use_count is through a shared_ptr. By definition, the deleter cannot have a valid reference to its own shared_ptr, only a weak_ptr

Yeah, I'm trying to understand a rather complicated piece of code that does indeed use a weak_ptr for this. Also I guess this question has a rather obvious answer now that you wrote it, I just got confused and didn't notice that there's no need to call the deleter in the first places unless the count gets to 0. Please make it an answer and I'll accept it.

I'm not sure if it matters for your use case, but the implementation defined control block that holds the implementation defined atomic count may have a different value (for example, one less than) than what use_count() returns.  Just to be aware of that if you're looking at the control block in a debugger and are puzzled why the numbers might be off-by-one.

The standard defines that the initial use_count is 1. Decrementing has to be atomic and the deleter must only be called once. For multiple threads to achieve this, the decrementing must be an atomic read-modify-write, ensuring that only one thread sees the final use_count reach zero. If it does, it calls the deleter.
Specifically: If multiple threads destroy their shared_ptrs at the same time, they will all potentially observe a use_count > 1 before decrementing but only one will observe it reaching 0. The count being greater than 1 before decrementing does not rule out that you're responsible for deleting afterwards. Therefore the deleter cannot possibly be called before decrementing.
Note that a deleter can only observe the use_count if it owns a weak_ptr to the same object since by definition it is called once the last shared_ptr to its own object has been destroyed, so it cannot have a valid reference to one. It cannot possibly be used to revive the object. Attempting to lock the weak_ptr will result in a default-contructed shared_ptr which, incidentally, is the only time you can observe use_count being zero.
Here is a simple example to show this:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


struct Foo: std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{};

struct Deleter
{
  void operator()(Foo* ptr) const
  {
    std::weak_ptr<Foo> weak = ptr->weak_from_this();
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> revived = weak.lock();
    std::cout << "Deleter reviving object? "
          << (revived ? "true" : "false") << '\n';
    delete ptr;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> f { new Foo, Deleter{} };
}

The standard defines that weak_ptr::lock() creates a valid shared_ptr if use_count > 0. Specifically

Returns:  expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this), executed atomically.

with expired() being defined as

Returns: use_count() == 0

So if use_count() > 0 could possibly be observed, resurrecting objects would work, causing the deleter to invoke itself recursively in the example above. While I couldn't find any mention to this scenario in the standard, it seems reasonable that implementations avoid this.
While this example here is clearly dumb code, it can easily happen in production code that the deleter or the object's destructor invoke code that has access to a weak_ptr to the object that is being destroyed.

As of C++ 23, [util.smartptr.shared.dest], it does not specifically say one way or another whether use_count will be 0 before or after the the deleter is called on the owned object. It only specifies the following:

(1.1) If *this is empty or shares ownership with another shared_ptr instance (use_count() > 1), there are no side effects.
(1.2) Otherwise, if *this owns an object p and a deleter d, d(p) is called.
(1.3) Otherwise, *this owns a pointer p, and delete p is called.

It would therefore be up to the implementer of shared_ptr. That said, MSVC decrements prior to deletion. Not sure about Clang, ICC, or G++, but presumably they'd do the same.
